# How can I get the following Javascript functions to execute on more than one image/div?

Tags: javascript

I have the following hacked code to fadein text and fadeout an image on hover.  I want to repeat this affect on a second image/div but I can't get it to work. i tried copying all the scripting and changing the variable names (i.e. img2 instead of img1 etc.) and I tried adding multiple handlers to the existing code but it doesn't work.  Only one image will fade while the other one does not.  Please help.  If it is not abdunantly clear, I am a Jquery wannabe who has some HTMl skills and a rudimentary understanding of programming.  Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
    #imgContainer {
        position: relative;
    }
    #img1 {
        opacity: 100;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    #imgContainer div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 60px;`enter code here`
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var speed = 0.8;
    var fadeTimerImg, fadeTimerTxt;
    function fade(obj,dir){
        if(fadeTimerImg){clearInterval(fadeTimerImg);}
        if(fadeTimerTxt){clearInterval(fadeTimerTxt);}
        fadeTimerImg = setInterval(function(){setOpacity(obj,dir)},100);
        fadeTimerTxt = setInterval(function(){setOpacity(oTxtContainer,-dir)},100);
    }
    function setOpacity(obj,dir) {
        obj.curOpac = obj.curOpac + (speed * dir);
        if(obj.curOpac < 0){obj.curOpac = 0;}
        if(obj.curOpac > 10){obj.curOpac = 10;}
        if(typeof(obj.style.opacity) == 'string'){
            obj.style.opacity = obj.curOpac/10;
        } else {
            obj.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + obj.curOpac*10 + ')';
        }
    }
    window.onload=function(){
        var oImg1 = document.getElementById('img1');
        oImg1.curOpac = 10;   //10 = opaque
        oTxtContainer = document.getElementById('txtContainer');
        oTxtContainer.curOpac = 0;  //0 = transparent
        oImg1.onmouseover = function(){fade(this,-1);}
        oImg1.onmouseout = function(){fade(this,1);}
    }
</script>

<div id="imgContainer">
    <div id="txtContainer">
        s`enter code here`ome text<br />
        more text <br />
        some more text
    </div>
    <img id="img1" src="FRY751_A.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I see JavaScript but I don't see any jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add the same class to each image, and do this, for example:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var $images = $('.my-image-class');

    $images.each(function() {
        $(this).curOpac = 10;   //10 = opaque
        $(this).onmouseover = function(){fade(this,-1);}
        $(this).onmouseout = function(){fade(this,1);}
    });
}
```